# Optimize requests in Python

Tags: python, optimization, python-requests

I'm writing a program to enumerate image files on a certain website, but the images are too big and `requests.get()` tries to get the whole image while I just need to know if the status code is 200 or not.

```
s = requests.Session()
for url in list_:
    req = s.get(url)
    if req.status_code == 200:
        print('FOUND!: {}'.format(url))
        with open('encontrados.txt', 'a') as f:
            f.write(url + '\n')
        else:
            pass
```

Is there any way I can optimize these requests so that the program doesn't take the image and only checks if the connection is possible?

Comment: Use a `HEAD` request instead of `GET`.

Comment: John Gordon is right, there's special HTTP method HEAD which retrieve just headers. However, some servers reject HEAD requests so in case if you'll face any issues with HEAD, you can use `stream` argument which will mimic HEAD behavior  `req.get(url, stream=True) ; req.close()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HEAD requests instead.

```py
import requests

r = requests.head("<url>")
r.status_code
```

This will get you a status code instead of the content.
You can check this out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/HEAD for some more info on HEAD requests.